# What is causing my rating in Magento to duplicate?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, php

Why is my rating having a duplicate values?

[image]

below is my **view.phtml** look like. I'm using Magento "**ver. 1.6.0.0**"

```
<?php if( $this->getRating() && $this->getRating()->getSize()): ?>
            <h3><?php echo $this->__('Product Rating:') ?></h3>
            <table class="ratings-table">
            <?php foreach ($this->getRating() as $_rating): ?>
                <?php if($_rating->getPercent()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode())) ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo ceil($_rating->getPercent()) ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check your configuration in backend? Under Catalog -> Reviews and Ratings -> Manage Rating. Maybe they are double configured. Otherwise it seems to be a data problem.

cheers

Comment: thanks for your response. But I think It doesn't have any duplicate configurations http://i42.tinypic.com/29y03ue.jpg

Answer (score 3):

this seems to be a problem in your database. If you started with sample data and deleted those reviews in the admin panel, the tables aren't deleted. So the 'review_id' is written two times to the database.

After taking a backup of your database follow these steps:

First of all delete all sample reviews from the table 'review_detail'. Keep the 'review_id' of the deleted reviews in mind.

Now delete all lines with the list of 'review_id' from above in the table 'rating_option_vote'.